# WSO2 ESB Server endpoint on localhost

Tags: apache-axis, esb, wso2, wso2-esb

Hello I have uploaded wso2-esb 4.0.3 on a server, the problem is that for every Proxy service I create, the ESB generates an incorrect endpoint:

for example, for Echoproxy it gives me an endpoint `http://**localhost**:8280/services/echo while it should be http://192.168.....:8280/services/echo`

What is the problem? some configuration of the ESB/
please suggest!!

**EDIT**: I have changed the `ServerURL` and the `HostName` in the `carbon.xml` file, but still appear **localhost** in the url endpoint. I don't know what else should I change..
also 
change

```
 <parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">192....</parameter>
```

in axis2.xml

still not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://myhost:8243</parameter-->
```

and

```
<parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">http://myhost:8280</parameter>
```